# Animate imageview in xamarin android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android, android-animation, android-imageview

I'm developing a Xamarin.Android app. When the main screen launches, it shows a logo centered in the screen. I want to scale up the logo with an animation when the application launches. Right now the only thing that isn't working is starting the animation. I've also noticed that i can't set other properties on the view. It doesn't give an error when executed, but nothing happens on the screen.
This is my main layout file:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:background="#000000">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/logo"
        android:id="@+id/logo"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

And this is my Main.cs file:

```
using Android.App;
using Suite17v2.Core.ViewModels;
using MvvmCross.Platform;
using Suite17v2.Core.Services.Interfaces;
using Android.Util;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.Animation;
using Android.Views.Animations;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Suite17v2.Droid.Views
{
[Activity(
    Theme = "@style/BaseTheme")]
public class MainActivity : BaseActivity<MainContainerViewModel>
{
    protected override int ActivityLayoutId => Resource.Layout.layout_login;
    ImageView logo;
    protected override void OnViewModelSet()
    {
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.layout_login);
        var parseService = new ParseService.Service.ParseService();
        Mvx.RegisterSingleton<IParseService>(parseService);
        base.OnViewModelSet();
        logo = FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.logo);

        logo.Animate().TranslationX(500).SetDuration(1000).SetStartDelay(0).Start(); //this doesnt work
        logo.SetX(450);//this also doesn't work


    }

    }
}
```

Comment: do you want animation on splash screen ?

Comment: @G.hakim no, at this point the application has already shown the splash screen. This is the main activity.

Comment: So at the start of your main activity you want an animation of some kind?